# inserting blob/clob over dblinks

Tags: oracle, blob, dblink, clob

I'm trying to find the best way to load a remote table with a blob column (blob only contains text, so clob would have been better).

So far we've been able to reduce loadtime from 218 minutes to 2 minutes using a view on the source table and converting the blob to varchar2 using (simplified):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "TABLE_V" ("ID", "DATE", "CLOB_PT1", "CLOB_PT2", "CLOB", CONSTRAINT "TABLE_V_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") RELY DISABLE) AS
  SELECT
  "ID",
  "DATE",
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(BLOB, 2000, 1)) "CLOB_PT1",
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(BLOB, 2000, 2001)) "CLOB_PT2",
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(INHOUD) > 4000 THEN TO_CLOB(BLOB) END "CLOB"
  FROM OWNER.TABLE;
```

Because we cannot guarantee the size of the blob will continue to fit in our two varchars we put anything bigger into a separate clob column in the view.
now the idea is to merge the varchars or clob back to one clob in our staging area.

Here come's the challenge of `ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables`

Concatenating the two varchars into the targeted clob column works fine.

```
INSERT 
  /*+  APPEND PARALLEL  */ 
  INTO SA.TESTTABLE
  (
    ID ,
    DATE ,
    CLOB
  ) 
SELECT 
  TABLE_V_1.ID ,
  TABLE_V_1.DATE , 
  TABLE_V_1.CLOB_PT1||TABLE_V_1.CLOB_PT2
FROM 
  OWNER.TABLE_V_1@DB_LNK TABLE_V_1
```

Inserting the clob into the targeted clob column works fine.

```
INSERT 
  /*+  APPEND PARALLEL  */ 
  INTO SA.TESTTABLE
  (
    ID ,
    DATE ,
    CLOB
  ) 
SELECT 
  TABLE_V_1.ID ,
  TABLE_V_1.DATE , 
  CLOB
FROM 
  OWNER.TABLE_V_1@DB_LNK TABLE_V_1
```

Using a 'case when' inserting either the concatenated varchars or the clob column fails!

```
INSERT 
  /*+  APPEND PARALLEL  */ 
  INTO SA.TESTTABLE
  (
    ID ,
    DATE ,
    CLOB
  ) 
SELECT 
  TABLE_V_1.ID ,
  TABLE_V_1.DATE , 
  CASE WHEN CLOB IS NOT NULL
    THEN TABLE_V_1.CLOB_PT1||TABLE_V_1.CLOB_PT2
    ELSE TABLE_V_1.INHOUD_CLOB
  END
FROM 
  OWNER.TABLE_V_1@DB_LNK TABLE_V_1
```

I also tried concatenating all three columns by default, (varchars1 and 2 will be empty if size blob >4000), same error.

Why is this failing?
Any suggestions on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

To insert lobs over a database link, your inserts need to be in the form:

INSERT INTO table1@remote_site SELECT * FROM local_table;

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_working.htm#ADLOB45148

You can do this by:

- Creating a temporary table
- Loading your clob data into the temp table
- The insert over the DB link with "insert@link .. select"

For example:

create table t (
id int,
x clob
);

create global temporary table gtt (
id int,
x clob
) on commit preserve rows;

declare
l clob;
begin
insert into gtt values ( 1, empty_clob() )
returning x into l;

for i in 1 .. 10 loop
dbms_lob.writeappend(l, 4000, lpad('x', 4000, 'x'));
end loop;

commit;

insert into t@loopback
select * from gtt;
end;
/

select id, length(x) from t;

```
    ID  LENGTH(X)
```

---

```
     1      40000
```

(Loopback is a DB link pointing back to the same database)

Comment: I believe our query is in that format but the other way around. We are inserting from a dblink, not into a dblink. I'm positive it is the 'case when' part of the select that is causing this error but I don't understand why this could cause such a problem.
You mentioning the temp table did gave me the solution though. As we are doing this with ODI I had to set the "USE_STAGING_TABLE" option in the LKM to true and now it works.
Wish we didn't have to create an aditional table though.